# SDN4 : How to define the depth for a query derived from finder-method names?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have defined a repository as follows:

```
public interface ServiceRepository extends GraphRepository<Service> 
{
    List<Service> findByName(String name);
}
```

Calling findByName on the repository works such that it does indeed return a list of Service items with matching name property. 
However, the Service entity contains nested entities and I need to be able to override the default depth of 1 for this query.

Is there anyway to define the depth for this query as there is with the .findAll(int) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment derived queries do not allow you to specify a depth different from the default (1).